# Multiple criteria on a SUMIF in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to see how many pounds of meat that I create, I consume.

So I have 3 columns... A: Pounds Sold, B: Customer, C: Batch

I want to see how many pounds of meat from batch "A" have been consumed by customer: EMPLOYEE.

I know how to use SUMIF but as far as I have tried I can only have 3 arguments.

Edit:

I figured out how to do this while creating a SUMIF. A SUMIFS popped up and told me that I can do multiple criteria!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out there is a SUMIFS which is the same thing as a SUMIF but in different order and has multiple criteria.